# How to monitor GitHub commits of a third-party repository

Tags: github, version-control, repository

Beginner here.

I've starred a GitHub repository created and managed by someone else. Is there a way to monitor commits and send an email to the listener every time someone checks in to the master branch?

Please note that I do not own the repo. I simply want to follow changes on a repository I like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get an [Atom feed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(standard)) of the repository's activity like this (using Node.JS `master` as an example):

```
https://github.com/nodejs/node/commits/master.atom
```

Use any Atom reader like [ViennaRSS](https://github.com/ViennaRSS/vienna-rss) for Mac or [RSS Feed Reader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rss-feed-reader/pnjaodmkngahhkoihejjehlcdlnohgmp?hl=en) for Chrome, or a variety of other feed readers. Many web-based Atom/RSS readers can e-mail you when events occur.