# Getting the last 100 commits in repositories of a GitHub user/organisation in Bash?

Tags: bash, git, github, github-api, commit

### Context

I wrote the following code to get the last `n` commits of a repository of a GitHub user/organisation:

```
    # Get commits
    commits_json=$(curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" https://api.github.com/repos/$github_username/$github_repo_name/commits?per_page=1&page=1)
    echo "commits_json=$commits_json"
    echo ""

    # Get the first commit.
    readarray -t branch_commits_arr <  <(echo "$commits_json" | jq ".[].sha")
    echo "branch_commits_arr=$branch_commits_arr"
```

### Issue

I noticed I get into the [reported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53528422/7437143)  rate limits of 60 API calls per hour when I try to do this for all repositories in a GitHub user/organisation.

### Attempt I

I tried the more general format to get the commit lists in a single API call:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" https://api.github.com/repos/$some_user/commits?per_page=10&page=1
```

Which returned:

> {  "message": "Not Found",
> "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#get-a-repository"
> }

### Attempt II

Another approach to get the data without triggering the API rate limit would be to parse the [atom format of each repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38336595/7437143), however, it seems like this is an undesirable hack/more boilerplate code than needed.

### Question

Hence, I was wondering, how can one get a list/json of/containing all/the most recent 100/`n` commits across all the repositories of a GitHub user/organisation, using the GitHub API in Bash?

Comment: Bash is not the problem. The problem is if that feature exists on GitHub API

Comment: by 'last 100 commits' is it meant on 'main' branch or across ***all*** branches on the remote?

Comment: Accross all branches on the GitHub repository (remote).

Comment: what about checkout locally all the repo with the last 100 commits ? `git clone --depth 100 git@github.com:foo/bar.git`

Comment: @Ôrel, thank you, that currently is my approach, sort of, however I am trying to save some bandwidth by downloading only the repositories that I need. And to determine which I need, requires me to evaluate their commits against a local or public list.